# Odoo 11: get cron id or name inside the called method for ir.cron that are create manually not just the ones that are created from XML

Tags: python, cron, odoo, odoo-11

I assigned (m2o) to my_object a cron (Automation->Scheduled Actions).
The cron execute (Python code) a method.
I need to have the id (or name) of the cron that call the method inside the method to do some actions on the objects assigned to the cron.

I think that the cron-object is not defined when the method execute, but it can be when the method is called. So I think that the way is to pass the id as argument but I don't know how to do so. I tried with "env" without succes.

Cron Python code

```
<record id="myobject_cron_task" forcecreate='True' model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">MyModel Task</field>
    <field name="active" eval="True" />
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_my_object"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">model.my_method(cron_id)</field>
</record>
```

Method

```
def my_method(self, active_cron_id):
    sel_objec = self.env['my.object'].search([('cron_id', '=', active_cron_id)])
    print(sel_objec)
```

NB: same question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961436/how-to-pass-cron-id-as-arg-in-method-that-the-cron-calls) without solution

Comment: Please tag odoo version so that people can understand which version are you working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the database `id` of `crons` that are created from `setting` menu `(no xml_id)`.

It turns out that odoo passed the same `context` also to the execution so anything you add to `context` you will find it in the `context` of `self` in your `method`, so just add the `Id` of the `cron` in the `context` by just overriding two `method`:

```py
from odoo import models, api

class IrCron(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.cron'

    @api.model
    def _callback(self, cron_name, server_action_id, job_id):
        """ to handle cron thread executed by Odoo."""
        self = self.with_context(cron_id=job_id)
        return super(IrCron, self)._callback(cron_name,server_action_id, job_id)

    @api.multi
    def method_direct_trigger(self):
        """ to handle manual execution using the button."""
        for rec in self:
            # rec = rec.with_context(cron_id=rec.id)
            super(IrCron, rec).method_direct_trigger()
        return True
```

and in your method:

```py
def my_method(self):
    cron_id = self.env.context.get('cron_id', False)
    if cron_id:
        cron = self['ir.cron'].browse(cron_id)
        print(cron)
```

I tested this and It work hope it's easy for you, and no need to pass any argument or anyting in the cron. Hope this what you are looking for.
By default Odoo logic don't provide this information so you need to change this behavior. no easy way to do it.

Comment: Your code give me ```name 'cron_id' is not defined``` evaluating the cron Python code

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove it from the call,  just use it as a keyword arguement, don't pass it as arguement sorry about that check my edits

Comment: I tried it before but now the message is ```External ID not found in the system: app_name.myobject_cron_task``` always evaluating Python code.

Comment: Yes you should replace the app_name by the name of the folder,  like. `sale.som_xmli_id` or `purchase.som_xml_id`, what is the name of the folder that contains `__manifest__.py` replace `app_name` with it

Comment: I fixed the error and now it works but don't solves the problem. 
To have different results I have to change the xml-id called ```cron_id="app_name.myobject_cron_task"``` to ex. ```cron_id="app_name.myobject2_cron_task"``` and these means that I have to preset all the crons with xml. 
What happen if I duplicate a cron? It returns the id of the original one, instead I need the id of the new one.

Comment: I have some bad news for you, there is no way to get the database id of the ir.cron inside the code, I checked the variable passed to `safe_eval` nothing contains the ID, so I came up with an Idea to work around that , and retrieve the ID of cron by a special key in the name of the cron this will work for sure hope you find it easy to implement good luck

Comment: Thanks for your edit but I did a similar thing as first solution simply adding a filed m2o cron_key to the object ```cron_key = fields.many2one("myobject.cronkey", "Cron Key")```, passing the key name in method call ```<field name="code">model.my_method('my_cron_key')</field>``` and filtering object on the associated key ```def my_method(self, active_key):
    sel_objec = self.env['my.object'].search([('cron_key', '=', active_key)])``` 
I keep trying, mybe the solution is behind the corner.

Comment: Okay I think I found a simple solution for by just override two method of `ir.cron` to pass the Id.

Comment: sorry about docs string I mixed them, `method_direct_trigger` is the one called from the button.

Comment: You anticipated me: these solves the problem (I only unchecked the comment on method_direct_trigger rec var). You are right that these solution could be a problem if something will change in the future but for now it is the only solution. In case, it can be usefull to create a PR to integrate the base model. Well done Charif!

Comment: good news for you it doesn't change any thing, it's a perfect solution I didn't override any method code, I just called them after adding a key to context. don't worry about it, I thought that I have to rewrite the code of `_callback` to pass the id for `safe_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code.

```
def my_method(self, active_cron_id):
    cron = self.env.ref('module_name.myobject_cron_task')
    print(cron)
```

Comment: your code give me ```External ID not found in the system: module_name.myobject_cron_task```

Comment: Replace the module_name by the actual module name that you have,  the name of your app, the folder that contains your costum module and do the same in my answer too

Comment: Thanks @CharifDZ (I'm not a dragon on Odoo/Python ;-)) and I confirm that with different cron that call the same method the returned id is only one.